pip install itself fails with "No module named 'distutils'"
I use Windows 11 and Python 3.12.5 64-bit, installed from https://www.python.org/downloads/
I'm trying to install requirements from some repo, but this fails:
PS C:\Data\Repos\myrepo> pip install -r .\requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\jonathanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jonathanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\jonathanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\jonathanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\jonathanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

From several questions on this site (best one) I understand distutils was removed in Python 3.12, and if I want to use them I should run pip install setuptools. I tried that, and it failed the same way.
So question: How can I use pip to restore requirements?

I found that this problem was solved in Python 3.12.6.
Update: Happened again with Python 3.13.0 - reverting to 3.12.6 for now.
Update: Now pip 3.12.6 also had a similar problem (not the same), and now 3.13.0 does work ¯_(ツ)_/¯
